# html5/jquery back button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a library or piece of code that makes a specific button act as like a proper browser back button where it will take you to the previous page that was loaded before?

At the moment I'm just specifying the `href` of what I assume was the page that was previously loaded but came to the conclusion that this won't work because a screen could have been accessed from different screens.

Is there an example of this or do I need to create my own logic that tracks page history some how?

Thanks

Comment: are you using single-file or multi-files template?

Comment: single file atm but will move my JS in a JS file later

Comment: use `$.mobile.changePage()` in jQM as mentioned in my answer. check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YMTzU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate back - **Single-file** template:

```
$('.selector').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
  $.mobile.changePage(page, {
    transition: 'flip',
    reverse: true
  });
});
```

Navigate back - **Multi-files** template:

```
$('.selector').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = document.referrer;
  $.mobile.changePage(page, {
    transition: 'flip',
    reverse: true
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GGfmT/show/)**

Comment: Doesnt go back to the screen

Comment: @jonney are you navigating between pages or .html files?

Comment: .html files i am navigating across

Comment: @jonney goof luck buddy :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the JavaScript back method;

```
function backButton() {
    window.history.back()
}

<a onclick="backButton()">Go back</a>
```

Or a different method;

```
<a onclick="history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
```

Comment: or for those of us that don't like to place code inside html, a pure js approach:`$('body').find('.go-back').on('click', function(){window.history.back();});` with the html:`<a class="go-back">Go back</a>`

Comment: @jonney The answer is correct but you'll lose transition effect.

Comment: How do i fix the transition effect?