# Jquery mobile ''pagebeforeshow' not executing after pressing back

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i have implemented some logic inside

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mainPage', function(){ 
}
```

but it doesnt load when a user eitehr presses the back key to go back to this specific page containg this JS or when calling

```
history.back(-1); return false;
```

to manually go back to the previous page.

It only gets executed if you do a refresh or directly go to the page using a href<>

Any sugestions?

cheers

Comment: try `$mobile.changePage()` instead of `history-back(-1)`

Comment: i tried both $('#mobile').changePage(); return false; and $('#mobile').changePage(); return false; and it could not fine the variable $mobile

Comment: This way http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545211/1771795 Also, if you remove `return false;` it should work. However, I still prefer the code in that answer.

Comment: That's the reason they've got `data-rel=back` in jqm.that'll take care of everything. What's your constraint in using that?

Comment: nothing. no constraint. did not know such a ,ethod existsed and when i oroginally googled how to go back to previous page, most links suggested using history.back so i used that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using multi-files template, you need to fetch previous URL from history `document.referrer`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7eRY6/show/)**

```
$('.selector').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = document.referrer;
  $.mobile.changePage(page, {
    transition: 'flip',
    reloadPage: true, // optional, force page reload.
    reverse: true
  });
});
```