# Refresh page after back button pressed jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-refresh

I am trying to create a jQuery mobile app where it will be having a login page and two more pages.

After login I'm going to the first page. From there I am navigating to the second page using `href` with data transition and using `history.back();` to go back. I would like to use the `pageshow()` event to update a listview using jQuery but it is not getting fired.

Which event do I have to use in this situation? This is the code I have tried so far:

```
jQuery( "#demo-page" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) 
 {
  alert( "This page was just hidden: " + ui.prevPage );
 });


$("#mback").click(function(){
if($("#mback").text()=='Back'){
//history.back();
var page = document.referrer;
  $.mobile.changePage(page, {
    transition: 'flip',
    reloadPage: true, // optional, force page reload.
    reverse: true
  });

/*$.mobile.changePage( "fff/ghouse/fff/home.php", {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: true

});*/
}
});
```

Comment: it's not being fired because your using `history.back()`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17728598/1771795

Comment: i tried your code but nothing happening if you want i will post my code

Comment: i have updated my question .i have just started learning jquery mobile so the way i use code is may not be right please spare me

Comment: You dont need if-statement for back button. what versions of jQ and jQM are you using?

Comment: i am using jquery-1.9.1,jquery.mobile-1.3.1 and that if block is for another purpose and one more thing i have jst clear cache and it is working but instead of going to prev page it is going to home page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33761/discussion-between-omar-and-ghouse)