# JQuery Mobile - history back breaks firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

So I'm working on a big system using JQM and the problem I'm running into is that after I use a history.go(-1) to change page (with a cancel button) firefox breaks entirely. All pages on all open firefox windows and tabs no longer display correctly, and some of the UI buttons are even becoming more transparent. The page that I transition to has all coloration replaced with solid black. I don't know what to do to debug this because I don't know what's actually happening here. Could someone possibly explain what's happening to firefox?

Note: I have attempted to pick up an error message in the console, but when the firefox javascript console is open, the bug stops happening.

Comment: did u try window.history.back(); instead of history.go(-1)

Comment: I have just tried it, and received the same result.

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage()` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545211/1771795